# Is there a way to open chrome devtools and ensure that console tab is selected

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-devtools-protocol

When you do command+option+i on this page, it will open the devtools. When it opens it will be focused on the last tab that was focused.

You can change the focused tab (from "Element" pane to "Console" or others) and then next time devtools opens, it will be focused on the last open pane.

Is there a way to ensure that devtools always opens with "Console" pane in focus?

Comment: https://www.canidev.tools/open-console-keyboard/chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use command + option + j to always open the Console!
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/open/#console

[image]